# Как выбрать только последние строки с максимальным id в таблице в MySQL?

Tags: php, select, mysql

Есть таблица:

```
id  people      text
1      1       Привет
2      1       Я Вася
3      1       Узнала?
4      2       Привет
5      2       Нет
6      3       А я Петя
7      1       Привет Петя
8      1       И Вася
9      2       Я Катя
...   ...      .....
```

Как сделать выборку, чтобы выбрались только строки с максимальным id у каждого people? То есть:

```
8      1       И Вася
9      2       Я Катя
6      3       А я Петя
```

Пока что придумала только выбирать все записи, сортировать в обратном порядке и брать только строки с не повторяющимися people для дальнейшей работы. Но, чувствую, со временем, объём данных для выборки будет слишком большим, поэтому необходимо сразу брать только нужное, если это возможно.

Comment: нече не понятно =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT people, MAX(id) AS id
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY 1
) q ON (q.people = t.people) AND (q.id = t.id)
```

Подзапрос `q` формирует максимальные `id` по каждому `people`. А `JOIN` дает возможность вывеси остальную информацию из таблицы для этих `id`.

Comment: @KiTE, напиши мне почту что-нибудь, у меня есть ещё вопросы. :-) Вот адрес - angelinastervochka@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

Вроде иначе никак:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(people) as _people, text FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, спасибки. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.id IN (
  SELECT MAX(t2.id)
  FROM table_name t2
  GROUP BY t2.people
)
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Можно еще так.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT status_comment, status_gamers FROM #__mod_gamers 
WHERE gamers_subm_id='.$subm_id.' ORDER BY org_subm_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table`) - 3 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3
```

Намного легче