# Выбор последней записи в 4 категориях

Tags: mysql

есть таблица курсов 4-х валют

```
id, datetime, валюта, курс.
```

В таблице в перемешку валюты с курсами.
Как вытащить 4 последних курса? (если смотреть на дату).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/315689/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/96063/186083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ:

```
SELECT t.* FROM `currency` t INNER JOIN ( SELECT ccy, MAX(id) AS id FROM `currency` GROUP BY 1 ) q ON (q.ccy = t.ccy) AND (q.id = t.id)
```

(ccy - поле с наименованием валюты)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 4;
```